# display resolution is not what is set

Tags: 12.04, resolution

I have an Acer eMachines e727 with Intel GMA 4500M graphics. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 using wubi on Win7. When I look at display from Dash it shows 1024x768, but what I am actually seeing looks more like 800x480.  What's going on and how do I get it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

In System Settings,  at Display Settings, you can change your monitor resolution to the proper value.